# Google Play: "The server could not process your apk. Try again."

Tags: android, apache-flex, flash-builder, google-play

I have been unable to upload a specific application to the Play store.  I'm using Flash Builder 4.6 to package it.

After the upload is complete I get the message "The server could not process your apk. Try again." I've tried about 20 times with different configurations over the course of 3 days. No luck.

The problem must be with the apk because I successfully uploaded another test.apk file to check the server.

I have tried the following:

1) Delete  tag (didn't have one so that's okay)

2) Run aapt dump badging and fixed errors (there were none)

3) Copied the manifest from another uploaded apk and just replaced the relevant data (package, name etc.)

The android manifest part of the app.xml file.

```
 <android>
    <colorDepth>16bit</colorDepth>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
        <manifest android:installLocation="preferExternal">
            <!--See the Adobe AIR documentation for more information about setting Google Android permissions-->
            <!--Removing the permission android.permission.INTERNET will have the side effect
    of preventing you from debugging your application on your device-->
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
            <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>-->
            <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>-->
            <!--The DISABLE_KEYGUARD and WAKE_LOCK permissions should be toggled together
    in order to access AIR's SystemIdleMode APIs-->
            <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>-->
            <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>-->
            <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>-->
            <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>-->
            <!--The ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE and ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permissions should be toggled
    together in order to use AIR's NetworkInfo APIs-->
            <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>-->
            <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>-->
        </manifest>

    ]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>
```

Anyone have any theories?  Totally out of ideas at this stage...

Cheers!

EDIT: Output of aapt d badging:

```
package: name='air.com.tspoon.BF3Loadouts' versionCode='1000000' versionName='1.0.0'
application-label:'BF3 Tactics'
application-label-ja:'BF3 Tactics'
application-label-de:'BF3 Tactics'
application-label-nl:'BF3 Tactics'
application-label-pl:'BF3 Tactics'
application-label-ko:'BF3 Tactics'
application-label-fr:'BF3 Tactics'
application-label-tr:'BF3 Tactics'
application-label-cs:'BF3 Tactics'
application-label-es:'BF3 Tactics'
application-label-it:'BF3 Tactics'
application-label-pt:'BF3 Tactics'
application-label-ru:'BF3 Tactics'
application-label-sv:'BF3 Tactics'
application-label-zh_CN:'BF3 Tactics'
application-label-zh_TW:'BF3 Tactics'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
application: label='BF3 Tactics' icon='res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png'
launchable-activity: name='air.com.tspoon.BF3Loadouts.AppEntry'  label='BF3 Tactics' icon=''
sdkVersion:'8'
targetSdkVersion:'14'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-implied-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE','requested  WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen','assumed you require a touch screen unless explicitly made optional'
main
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--' 'ja' 'de' 'nl' 'pl' 'ko' 'fr' 'tr' 'cs' 'es' 'it' 'pt' 'ru' 'sv' 'zh_CN' 'zh_TW'
densities: '120' '160' '240'
native-code: 'armeabi-v7a'
```

Comment: can you post the output of the `aapt -d badging` command?
also, that `<![CDATA[` looks a little strange to me, but I may be wrong on that.

Comment: I don't know about Flash, but are you using a keystore other than the android-debug key?

Comment: Did you create a Release Build w/ Flash Builder?  Or are you attempting to upload a "Debug" Version?  I don't believe that the 'debug' versions are signed w/ a cert.

Comment: Edited to include aapt d badging command.  Sorry, there's a bunch of commented out stuff in the <![CDATA[ tag. And yes it's release build. I'm using the keystore I generated with Flash, so I guess not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: After contacting Google Play Developer support I found out the issue....

```
My icon files were too big!
```

My icons were about 140k each, and as soon as I reduced them to 10k it worked perfect!

Answer (score 0):

If you use drawable file for the icon from android standard icons like @android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert. the parser failed to find the ic_dialog_alert file in the res/drawable directory and raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have an error in your manifest xml file.

In your SDK platform tools you can find aapt

Run this
aapt dump badging

Got the answer from this [link](http://www.androidpit.com/en/android/forum/thread/496760/Google-play-The-server-could-not-process-your-apk-Try-again#p1292500)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using Flash Builder 4.6

I had successfully uploaded version 0.9.45. I then went up to 0.9.5 but kept getting the 'you must upload a version higher than 0945' error. I tried all sorts of things, including the suggestion of making icon sizes much smaller. Nothing worked.

Finally I decided just to change to 1.0.0 and then it was accepted by Google Play(!)