# AIR as3 APK works on device, but it fails when sending to google play

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I've being having trouble with an app I'm developing for Android.
I'm using Flash CS 5.5 with air 14 (updated it last weekend) and when I build it and transfer the app into an android device, it runs normally.
But when I try to upload it to google play, they simply said it fails to send but don't give me any decent info.
Did it happen to anyone ?  Does anybody has any idea ?

I searched it for more than 3 hours with no luck at all.
I saw this post here: [Google Play: "The server could not process your apk. Try again."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773163/google-play-the-server-could-not-process-your-apk-try-again)
Even thought of the size of icons, but they aren't that big. I'll still ask the artist to make them a little bit smaller, just in case.
I'm still searching how to extract the "aapt -d badging" that people talked about there. Is it possible to do so in Windows ?  I saw tools for linux to do that.

Thanks for the patience.  =]

[ ]'s

Comment: what is your apk size ?

Comment: How do you build your final apk? Are you using the adt command line?

Comment: sounds like a signing issue - you can't just use the version that you're testing on, as it has special developer privileges

Comment: Shereef Marzouk - It's only 15.6MB.  I read about the 50MB limit, but we're still far from that.  =] /// Cristina Georgescu - I'm building it directly from Flash CS5.5 /// divillysausages - I asked the project manager for a "publishing certificate" (I know that Apple has different ones). He said that was the one. Is there another things I should change in flash but the publishing for device ?  (or is THIS the error ?)

Thanks for the answers so far !  =]